# php empty check on param returns false on not empty variable

Tags: php

```
class Renderer
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array();
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->data) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

When I check `empty($renderer->param)` it returns false even if `var_dump($renderer->param)` returns correct value.

Is it that php checks for parameter inside class when it's stored in array or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could (should?) implement an `__isset()` method. The [manual on `empty()` says:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> When using empty() on inaccessible object properties, the __isset() overloading method will be called, if declared.

Comment: For your convenience, here is a snipplet for what you want: https://gist.github.com/pinoniq/6039523

Comment: That was the case, thank you :) I would have had bad headache figuring it out, @Pinoniq thanks for snipplet too.